# A laptop with 512 ssd and 32gb ram within 1000-1300$ range?

Tags: laptop, portable

Titled mentioned are the main focusing criteria. Of course it should be i7 processor, a graphics card, 15" display and not too heavy to carry and a matt display.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your opinion in advance.

Comment: Maybe something from the Dell XPS line.

Comment: So the full requirements are:  i7 CPU, dedicated GPU, 15" matte display, 512GB SSD, 32GB ram, AND be in the 1000 to 1300 range, which I am assuming is USD?  I have no clue what is meant by "not too heavy" as the concept will differ from person to person.

Comment: Some of your listed requirements seem... arbitrary. What tasks do you plan to use this for? "Graphics card" and "should be i7" with no further explanation tell me you may not actually need these things.

Comment: portability that's what meaning lightweight and virtual machines etc

Answer (score 2):

For a system that is preconfigured with those specs, you are looking at a bit higher of a price range.  The lowest I could find via Newegg was an HP Envy for around $1700 USD.

I feel your best bet, would be to look at companies that build customized systems.

One such place is [XoticPC](http://www.xoticpc.com).

I'd look at customizing either of the following, to stay close to budget:

1. [MSI GP62 Leopard Pro-870](http://www.xoticpc.com/msi-gp62-leopard-pro870.html)
2. [ASUS GL552VW-DH71](http://www.xoticpc.com/asus-gl552vwdh71.html)